# How to duplicate cmake target

Tags: cmake

I am writing function in my cmake project that needs to make two targets from one, and alter slightly one of them:

```
option(BORG_STRIP_TEST_BINARIES OFF "Strip symbols from test binaries to reduce disk space usage" )
function(add_borg_test target)
    add_test(${target} ${target} --gtest_color=yes)
    if(BORG_STRIP_TEST_BINARIES)
        # copy target, but make it optional
        duplicate_target(FROM ${target} TO ${target}_debug )
        set_target_properties(${target}_debug PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
        # alter
        target_link_options(${target} PRIVATE -s)
    endif()
endfunction()
```

So this is supposed to work like this:

1. I create binary target that uses gtest. Set up all `target_link_libraries` and everything. Example name `example-utests`
2. instead add generic `add_test`, I use custom `add_borg_test`
3. now `example-utests` links with flag `-s` and is included in `all` target.
4. `example-utests_debug` is NOT included in `all` target but when requested explicitly, it links without `-s`.

How to implement `duplicate_target` from above code snippet?

Comment: I don't know a way to duplicate a target in CMake. You need to create new target from scratch. For create two targets with similar properties you could create a macro or a function, which creates a single target and fills its common properties. You may call this macro twice, for create two targets. Then separately adjust those properties for targets which differs.

Comment: As alternative to the alternatives mentioned by Tsyvarev you could also use a `foreach` loop, e.g. `foreach(_TARGET_NAME IN ITEMS target_foo target_bar) ...` and assign/overwrite any properties unique to one of the targets after the end of the loop. Which approach works best depends on the things different between the targets.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct (sorry) is to question why one would want to do this. I'm not you and I don't know your context, so ask yourself this: Are you *sure* that you can't achieve what you want by just generating multiple buildsystems and specifying separate configuration options for each one? After all, the whole design of CMake is to make it easy to generate buildsystems.

---

That being said, if you are convinced that you have a good reason to want to copy/clone/duplicate a target definition *in the same buildsystem*, then do as suggested by Brad King (one of the CMake maintainers) in [this mailing thread](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2017-March/029902.html):

> There is no builtin way to do that, though you might be able to
> get close with a macro that reads target properties from the
> original in order to reproduce them with appropriate commands.

It will probably help to make use of [How to get all the properties of a target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69761538/11107541). Note that there are significant limitations which I list in my answer post there. The best solution I know of only allows for reading builtin-to-CMake target properties and not any that you or any other CMake config code defines customly. So the same limitation will apply to this solution here, which is something along the lines of:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "--help-property-list" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/--help-property-list.txt")
file(STRINGS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/--help-property-list.txt" property_list)
function(copy_target_props src_target dest_target)
  set(config_types "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}")
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    set(config_types "Release;Debug;RelWithDebInfo;MinSizeRel")
  endif()
  foreach(prop_name ${property_list})
    if("${prop_name}" MATCHES "(^LOCATION)|^VS_DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION$|^MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION$|^CXX_MODULE_SETS$|^HEADER_SETS$|^IMPORTED_GLOBAL$|^INTERFACE_CXX_MODULE_SETS$|^INTERFACE_HEADER_SETS$|^NAME$|^TYPE$")
      continue()
    endif()
    if("${prop_name}" MATCHES "<CONFIG>")
      foreach(config ${config_types})
        string(REPLACE "<CONFIG>" "${config}" config_prop_name "${prop_name}")
        get_target_property(prop_val "${src_target}" "${config_prop_name}")
        if(NOT "${prop_val}" STREQUAL "prop_val-NOTFOUND")
          #message("${config_prop_name}: ${prop_val}")
          set_property(TARGET "${dest_target}" PROPERTY "${config_prop_name}" "${prop_val}")
        endif()
      endforeach()
    else()
      get_target_property(prop_val "${src_target}" "${prop_name}")
      if(NOT "${prop_val}" STREQUAL "prop_val-NOTFOUND")
        #message("${prop_name}: ${prop_val}")
        set_property(TARGET "${dest_target}" PROPERTY "${prop_name}" "${prop_val}")
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()
  set(prop_name "IMPORTED_GLOBAL")
  get_target_property(prop_val "${src_target}" "${prop_name}")
  if((NOT "${prop_val}" STREQUAL "prop_val-NOTFOUND") AND "${prop_val}")
    #message("${config_prop_name}: ${prop_val}")
    set_property(TARGET "${dest_target}" PROPERTY "${prop_name}" "${prop_val}")
  endif()
endfunction()

# example usage
add_executable(foo1 foo.c)
add_executable(foo2)
copy_target_props(foo1 foo2)
```

I got too lazy to write an actual duplicating function where you don't need to define the second target manually. But you could do that by reading the target `TYPE` property of the source target and then if-elsing over all the `add_executable`/`add_library` variants (you can't change the type of a target after you first define it ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76078866/11107541))).

---

There's another technique with limited applicability- not so much for copying targets, but for making common target property setup reusable (again, with limited applicability): define INTERFACE properties on an [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries), and then link your multiple, similar targets to the interface target so they inherit the values from the interface target.

---

last tidbit: I have a project where I used CMake to drive PGO the two phases training and optimized build, where I made the project ExternalProject itself and defined two custom build configuration for the training and use phases, which require different compilation flags. That is to (rather unhelpfully) say that the suitability of what approach you take can depend on context.