# How to get all the properties of a target

Tags: cmake

In CMake, I want to get all property names that are set for a target.

In [How to print all the properties of a target in cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183975/how-to-print-all-the-properties-of-a-target-in-cmake) they use `cmake --help-property-list` to list a predefined set.
But if you have a target that defines other properties, how can I know which are they?
For example:

```
set_target_properties(some_target PROPERTIES some_custom_property prop_val)
```

How can I get all such properties? I am looking for something like

```
get_target_property_names(some_target property_names)
```

Comment: Do you know the solution to this problem yet?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Even the solution in your link for handling preset properties is very ugly to implement, I wonder if the new version has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, the latest CMake version is v3.25. I am not aware of any commands or functions which directly implement what you are looking for.

I tried looking to see if there was any special target property which lists names of all other target properties on a target, but didn't see such a property in the [list of target properties in the reference documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets).

I tried to see if there was any internal/undocumented functionality that tracked the names of all properties on a target. You can see the source code in the `cmTarget::SetProperty` and `cmTarget::StoreProperty` member functions in [KitWare/CMake/Source/cmTarget.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmTarget.cxx). There technically is, but not in a way that is simple, or that I can see any way to access from a CMake script. I say it isn't simple because when you look at `cmTarget::StoreProperty`, you'll see that many properties are handled and stored in custom ways other than the more general storage (`this->impl->Properties`).

Perhaps you could try to come up with a way to override the `set_target_properties` and `set_property` commands to track changes to them to know what custom properties are being added, and combine that knowledge with what can be gotten from [How to print all the properties of a target in cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32183975/11107541), but redefining CMake commands is [generally not a good idea / difficult to do right](https://crascit.com/2018/09/14/do-not-redefine-cmake-commands/).

At this point, you might want to think more about why you want to be able to do this and whether there are different ways to achieve what you want (Ie. this could be an XY Problem). You could ask your "Y"-Question as a separate question on Stack Overflow, or you could ask on [the CMake Discourse](https://discourse.cmake.org/). If you talk with the CMake maintainers in an issue ticket and agree that there's a good case for such functionality for general users of CMake, then (who knows!) it could become a feature in a later CMake version.

One idea at least for getting all the builtin target properties would be to call [`cmake --help-property-list`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-help-property-list) and then to loop over the listed properties and test which exist on the target. Ex.

```
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "--help-property-list" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/--help-property-list.txt")
file(STRINGS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/--help-property-list.txt" property_list)
function(read_target_props target)
  set(config_types "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}")
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    set(config_types "Release;Debug;RelWithDebInfo;MinSizeRel")
  endif()
  foreach(prop_name ${property_list})
    if("${prop_name}" MATCHES "(^LOCATION)|^VS_DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION$|^MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION$")
      continue()
    endif()
    if("${prop_name}" MATCHES "<CONFIG>")
      foreach(config ${config_types})
        string(REPLACE "<CONFIG>" "${config}" config_prop_name "${prop_name}")
        get_target_property(prop_val "${target}" "${config_prop_name}")
        if(NOT "${prop_val}" STREQUAL "prop_val-NOTFOUND")
          message("${config_prop_name}: ${prop_val}")
        endif()
      endforeach()
    else()
      get_target_property(prop_val "${target}" "${prop_name}")
      if(NOT "${prop_val}" STREQUAL "prop_val-NOTFOUND")
        message("${prop_name}: ${prop_val}")
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endfunction()

# example usage:
add_executable(foo foo.c)
read_target_props(foo)
```