# In CMake, can I mark a library as static after add_library'ing it?

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking, buildconfiguration

In CMake, we can write:

```
add_library(mylib mylib.c)
```

for a dynamically-linked (shared) library, and

```
add_library(mylib STATIC mylib.c)
```

for a static one. But - can we start with the first syntax, then later mark the `mylib` target as static?

Comment: You first snippet does not create a dynamic libary, only if `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is set. Maybe this is exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: @local-ninja: I've never set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS, and yet somehow dynamic libs were created...

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess (I feel pretty confident right now, but I don't want to come off as too confident) is that this is not possible.

For one thing, you can trace how the type argument of the `add_library` command gets parsed and eventually used to set data in internal CMake structures. Then you can try to see where else that data member is modified/modifiable and then look for "vectors" (in the "attack vector" sense of the word) into that execution path. I found none. Here's the call hierarchy for what I just mentioned:

- Source/cmAddLibraryCommand.cxx cmAddLibraryCommand
- Source/cmMakefile.cxx cmMakefile::AddLibrary
- Source/cmMakefile.cxx cmMakefile::AddNewTarget
- Source/cmMakefile.cxx cmMakefile::CreateNewTarget
- Source/cmTarget.cxx cmTarget::cmTarget, which does `this->impl->TargetType = type;`
- If you search for the regex "`\bTargetType\s*=[^=]`" in the rest of source code, you'll only see it in that previously mentioned `cmTarget::cmTarget` constructor.

And there's [the `TYPE` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/TYPE.html), but it's read-only. You'll get an error if you attempt to modify it.