# Is there a way to copy cmake target?

Tags: cmake, embedded

### Background

I'm doing some embedded development with an asymmetric dual core processor, which means they have different compile flags such as `-mcpu`, `-mfloat-abi` etc.

> different options make output completely incompatible

In case use some cmake libraries, one define a target for example "mylib", and I want to use it on all the cores. For the single core situation, I can use `add_compile_options` or `target_compile_options` to add the compile flags. But in dual core situation, there's only one library target which it can not accept two different sets of compile options.

Is there a way to copy a cmake target?

### What I wanted

```
add_executable(core0 ${CORE0_SRCS})
add_executable(core1 ${CORE1_SRCS})

add_subdirectory(mylib) # This create a static library `mylib`
copy_target(mylib mylib1) # wanted function which create a copy a library `mylib`

# Apply two different sets of compile options
target_compile_options(mylib ${CORE0_FLAGS})
target_compile_options(mylib1 ${CORE1_FLAGS})

target_link_libraries(core0 mylib)
target_link_libraries(core1 mylib1)
```

Comment: "Is there a way to copy a cmake target?" - No, there is no such way. See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882591/how-to-duplicate-cmake-target).

Comment: You could create a cmake function containing common logic. Alternatively you could add common stuff to an `INTERFACE` library (e.g. using `target_sources(MyInterfaceLib INTERFACE foo.cpp bar.cpp) target_include_directories(MyInterfaceLib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/some_include_dir) ...`) and link it to the individual libs.

Comment: I just wrote up https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160260/11107541

Comment: @fabian Sure I know this, but almost all the third party library defines a static library, very difficult to rewrite the cmake file in to an interface library

Comment: @starball nice try

Comment: @Logiase what do you mean by "nice try"? To what extent did my answer help you / solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

warning: not tested !

You could create a INTERFACE library `ilib` with INTERFACE target_sources and common compile/link options/definitions.

```
add_library(ilib INTERFACE)
target_sources(ilib INTERFACE ...)
target_compile_options(ilib INTERFACE ....)
```

Then create two specifics `c0lib`, `c1lib` core libraries linking to it:

```
add_library(c0lib)
target_compile_options(c0lib PRIVATE ...)
target_link_libraries(c0lib PRIVATE ilib)

add_library(c1lib)
target_compile_options(c1lib PRIVATE ...)
target_link_libraries(c1lib PRIVATE ilib)
```

So you should be able to populate both libraries and tweak them.